# BitmapFactory Not working in Android

Tags: java, android

This line of code always returns null after cropping:

```
this.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.imageFileUri.getPath());
```

This is my crop method:

```
 private void performCrop() {
      this.imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(this.file);
      Intent var1 = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
      var1.setDataAndType(this.imageFileUri, "image/*");
      System.out.println(this.imageFileUri.getPath());
      var1.putExtra("crop", "true");
      var1.putExtra("scale", true);
      var1.putExtra("return-data", true);
     // var1.putExtra("output", this.imageFileUri);
      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.imageFileUri);
      this.startActivityForResult(var1, 1);
   }
```

I have tried by using a custom method to return the Bitmap it still returns null. This is the method

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
       int orientation;
       try {
           if (path == null) {
               return null;
           }
           // decode image size
           BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
           // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
           final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
           int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
           int scale = 1;

           BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           o2.inSampleSize = scale;
           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
           Bitmap bitmap = bm;

           ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);

           orientation = exif
                   .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

           Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation =" + orientation);

           // exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);

           Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
           Matrix m = new Matrix();

           if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
               m.postRotate(180);
               // m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float) bm.getHeight());
               // if(m.preRotate(90)){
               Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
               bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                       bm.getHeight(), m, true);
               return bitmap;
           } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
               m.postRotate(90);
               Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
               bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                       bm.getHeight(), m, true);
               return bitmap;
           } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
               m.postRotate(270);
               Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
               bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                       bm.getHeight(), m, true);
               return bitmap;
           }
           return bitmap;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return null;
       }

   }
```

And calling the above method this way:

```
this.bmp = MyClass.decodeFile(this.imageFileUri.getPath());
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: in decodeFile(String path) what is passed as `path` param?

Comment: @pskink: It is the temporary image return from the Uri. Take a look: this.imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(this.file);

Comment: whats the value of String ?

Comment: The String returns the actual image path. which I can see on my console log message

Comment: This is the image returned from the log >>>>>./storage/sdcard0/Android/data/.....files/.temp_image217988436.jpg

Comment: whats the value of String ? does that file exist? is it empty? what about permissions? did you try `adb shell ls -l /the/path/to/the/file` ?

Comment: Yeah the path exists!

Comment: so copy that path to your dev box and try to show

Comment: This is the check:>>>>>>>>>> while(this.file.exists() && this.bmp == null) {
//             if (this.bmp == null) {
//                    break;
//                  }
               //Output something
               break;
            }

Comment: Decoding the cropped image returns null.

Comment: ok, what is the **exact** path?

Comment: It returns the actual path